# Why doesn't N('abs(2)') simplify to 2 in Sympy 1.5.1?

Tags: sympy

This is my code:

```
from sympy import *
from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import parse_expr
x, y, z, t = symbols('x y z t')
print(N('abs(2)'))
```

It returns `abs(2)` instead of `2` running on Jupyter Notebook on Anaconda. Isn't N() meant to evaluate numerical expressions?

I thought that when you give N() a string, it parses automatically, but just in case I checked:

```
expr = parse_expr('abs(2)')
print(N(expr))
```

This again returns `abs(2)`

Comment: Probably sympy expects [`Abs`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/functions/elementary.html?highlight=abs#sympy.functions.elementary.complexes.Abs) with a capital `A`. Sympy capitalizes some function names in order not to overwrite standard Python functions. Similar things happen with [`Max`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/functions/elementary.html?highlight=max#max) and `Or`.  *It is named Max and not max to avoid conflicts with the built-in function max.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is called `Abs` in sympy. What you get back from `parse_expr` is an arbitrary function that just happens to be called `abs`:

```
In [8]: parse_expr('f(2)')
Out[8]: f(2)

In [9]: parse_expr('abs(2)')
Out[9]: abs(2)

In [10]: parse_expr('Abs(2)')
Out[10]: 2
```